# Emberjs - Debugger not displaying errors when {{#each}} does not load models

Tags: javascript, debugging, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

I am using the {{#each}} handlebars to display a list of record names. The record names are not being displayed. I am receiving no errors and the Chrome Extension  Ember debugger only displays

```
"RecordCategories
recordCategories
<DS.RecordArray:ember923> Send to console
VpcYeoman.RecordCategoriesController Send to console
VpcYeoman.RecordCategoriesView Send to console"
```

in the /# Routes section of the debugger. Nothing appears in the Data section of the ember debugger under Record Categories either.

How am I suppose to find out where this error is coming from if both the Ember Debugger and the console don't acknowledge that there is an error? Am I missing something when I go into the Ember debugger? So far it has been completely useless, telling me information that I can mostly find in the normal Chrome Dev tools

```
Chrome Version  = 33.0.1750.152,
Ember --version = 0.2.8, (I'm not sure why it is displaying the ember tools version instead of the ember version)
Ember Data Version = ? ( i could not find where to check the version of this)
```

I should also mention that I had this working a couple days ago. I merged with another team's code and this problem occurred.

Comment: When you say "nothing" appears in the data section, do you mean you don't see the Model objects on the left-hand side?  Or do you mean that the `# Records` is zero?

Comment: Also please mention the versions you are using of Ember, EmberData and Chrome debugger.

Comment: I see the model objects on the side (App.RecordCategory) but the # Records is 0

Comment: I have posted the versions of Ember and chrome but I could not figure out what the command is to check my EmberData version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your question, how am I suppose to find out where this error is coming from:

1. Use logging in the template {{log model}}, {{log model.length}}
2. Inject the model into the page {{model}}, {{model.length}}
3. make the model a global variable and play with it in the console globalVar.get('length')

Ember doesn't report non-errors, aka, if you have no data, it isn't an error if the collection is empty. It would be an error if you attempted to iterate over a non-collection.

Comment: Do I need to place the {{log model}} in between the {{#each}} brackets for my model? The data had been displaying in an old version and only until I merged it with another team's code did it do this.

Comment: yeah, {{log this}} may be appropriate there as well, it's just a way of debugging stuff

Comment: This tool is very handy! Thanks for coming to the rescue (yet again). I fixed the bug which wasn't a bug but the addition of VpcYeoman.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({}); in store.js.

Comment: I asked another question related to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510544/emberjs-can-a-local-storage-adapter-and-a-data-storage-adapter-be-used-simulta