# Emberjs - Can a local storage adapter and a data storage adapter be used simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, adapter, data-storage

Can a local storage adapter and a data storage adapter be used simultaneously? Here's some example code.

```
VpcYeoman.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
      namespace: 'viewpoint-emberjs'
    });
```

vs.

```
VpcYeoman.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
        queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {            
            return fixtures.filter(function(item) {
                for(prop in query) {
                    if( item[prop] != query[prop]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    })
```

});

Fight! 
Or coexist??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  You can create per-type adapters, so you can have:

```
App.PostAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {            
        return fixtures.filter(function(item) {
            for(prop in query) {
                if( item[prop] != query[prop]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
});
App.Post.FIXTURES = [];
```

Your other non-fixture types can omit an `Adapter` and instead use the `ApplicationAdapter`, which could be an instance of `DS.RESTAdapter` or `LocalStorageAdapter`.  Optionally, you could define that adapter on the DS.Store instance.